# Sura 36:13 question

Tags: quran, tafseer, christianity, quran-translation

My son is reading the Quran and he is questioning Quran 36/13, he is connecting the names as explained in Ibn Kathir to what Christian mentioned about Paul, Simon, and he is saying this make Chritianity is right, i need help, here is the verse:

> ﴿مَّثَلاً أَصْحَـبَ القَرْيَةِ إِذْ جَآءَهَا الْمُرْسَلُونَ﴾
> (a similitude; the Dwellers of the Town, when there came Messengers to them.)

> In the reports that he transmitted from Ibn 'Abbas, Ka'b Al-Ahbar and Wahb bin Munabbih - Ibn Ishaq reported that it was the city of Antioch, in which there was a king called Antiochus the son of Antiochus the son of Antiochus, who used to worship idols. Allah sent to him three Messengers, whose names were Sadiq, Saduq and Shalum, and he disbelieved in them. It was also narrated from Buraydah bin Al-Husayb, `Ikrimah, Qatadah and Az-Zuhri that it was Antioch. Some of the Imams were not sure that it was Antioch, as we shall see below after telling the rest of the story if Allah wills.

> ﴿إِذْ أَرْسَلْنَآ إِلَيْهِمُ اثْنَيْنِ فَكَذَّبُوهُمَا﴾
> (When We sent to them two Messengers, they denied them both;) means, they hastened to disbelieve in them.

> ﴿فَعَزَّزْنَا بِثَالِثٍ﴾
> (so We reinforced them with a third,) means, 'We supported and strengthened them with a third Messenger. ' Ibn Jurayj narrated from Wahb bin Sulayman, from Shu'ayb Al-Jaba'i, "The names of the first two Messengers were Sham`un and Yuhanna, and the name of the third was Bulus, and the city was Antioch (Antakiyah).

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly disturbs your son? Just about translating names?

Comment: Islam and Christianity agree on many things. To say one is right in some aspect does not automatically say the other is wrong.

Comment: https://blog.fussilat.com/does-the-quran-approve-of-paul/

Comment: Salam and welcome to islamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that yu should clearly distinguish quotations from your own words I've edited your post trying to do this as good as I can. Further Christianity and Islam have a lot in common and the Qur'an actually mentioned many stories that are known to bother Jews and Christians beside others that are known in the Arabic Peninsula, why should this create confusion?

Answer (score 0):

Tafsir literature and the opinions of scholars in speculative exegesis is not definitive.